# component inside component Angular

Tags: angular, ng-template

What is it called when one component is inside another?
like in

```
<agm-map [latitude]="lat" [longitude]="lng">
  <agm-marker [latitude]="lat" [longitude]="lng"></agm-marker>
</agm-map>
```

And how it works?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to use `ng-content`

```
<ng-content></ng-content>
<ng-content select="agm-marker"></ng-content>
```

you have to declare two components as:

*agm-map.component.ts*

```
@Component({
    selector: 'agm-map',
    template: '<ng-content></ng-content>
            <ng-content select="agm-marker"></ng-content>'
})
export class AgmMapComponent {
  ...
}
```

*agm-marker.component.ts*

```
@Component({
    selector: 'agm-marker',
    template: '<div>Marker</div>'
})
export class AgmMarkerComponent {
  ...
}
```

But I guess you want to pass latitude/longitude to your child component for that you can read the documentation related to how to pass data from parent to child component [here](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction)

Answer (score 0):

I am fairly sure, that the middle component won't get rendered. It is an invalid sytax.

You can, however, create recursive component patterns with at least 2 different components, like this:

In a "recursion-container" component's html:

```
<agm-map ....
```

in agm-map component.html:

```
<recursion-container"...
```

So you basicly need a middle-layer for it.

On basic component communication, [you can read the documentation](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction)